# How to insert data of a list in a database properly?

Tags: python, mysql, list, tuples, mysql-python

I have the list as :

```
col1 = ['', '8465-01-446-8616', '8465-01-538-4334', '8345-01-641-8205', '8465-01-690-3107', '8465-01-526-7827', '', '', '5120-00-097-4136', '6640-00-866-1645']

col2 = [[], ['06222'], ['0N995', '12858'
], ['58367', '58367'], ['4SEN6'], ['0CCM0'], [], [], ['82523', '8BXN8'], ['1KGE8', '725Q0']]

col3 = [[], ['MODEL 703'], ['PMBS9', 'BS-9'], ['24425HBA', '37210'], ['MA66-002'], ['03485'], [], [], ['100250', '5080'], ['09-845C', '4716E20']]


col4 = [[], [''], ['AARDVARK', 'PAULSON MANUFACTURING CORPORAT
ION'], ['WILLARD MARINE, INC.', 'WILLARD MARINE, INC.'], ['CONDOR OUTDOOR PRODUCTS, INC.'], ['CASCADE DESIGNS, INC.'], [], [], ['', 'TELEFLEX LLC'], ['FISHER SCI
ENTIFIC COMPANY L.L.C.', 'THOMAS SCIENTIFIC, LLC']]
```

I have to insert these data into a database.

I tried first converting the list of list into a single list using

```
col2 = sum(col2,[])
col3 = sum(col3,[])
col4 = sum(col4,[])
```

and converting into a list of tuples using

```
records = list(zip(col1,col2,col3,col4))
```

records

```
[('', '06222', 'MODEL 703', ''), ('8465-01-446-8616', '0N995', 'PMBS9', 'AARDVARK'), ('8465-01-538-4334', '12858', 'BS-9', 'PAULSON MANUFACTURING CORPORATION'), ('8345-01-641-8205', '58367', '24425HBA', 'WILLARD MARINE, INC.'), ('8465-01-690-3107', '58367', '37210', 'WILLARD MARINE, INC.'), ('8465-01-526-7827', '4SEN6', 'MA66-002', 'CONDOR OUTDOOR PRODUCTS, INC.'), ('', '0CCM0', '03485', 'CASCADE DESIGNS, INC.'), ('', '82523', '100250', ''), ('5120-00-097-4136', '8BXN8', '5080', 'TELEFLEX LLC'), ('6640-00-866-1645', '1KGE8', '09-845C', 'FISHER SCIENTIFIC COMPANY L.L.C.')]
```

There is a mismatch in this record.

and mysql query for inserting into a database:

```
conn = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="",
  user="",
  password="",
  database=""
)
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.executemany ( """
INSERT INTO table(col1,col2,col3,col4)
VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)
""" , records )

conn.commit ()
```

This created a mismatch of the above data:

The data in the database should be like:

```
,,,,
8465-01-446-8616,0622,MODEL 703,,
8465-01-538-4334,0N995,PMBS9,AARDVARK,
8465-01-538-4334,12858,BS-9,PAULSON MANUFACTURING CORPORATION
8345-01-641-8205,58367,24425HBA,WILLARD MARINE, INC.
8345-01-641-8205,58367,37210,WILLARD MARINE, INC.
```

A single list in all of the list of lists is linked to the element of col1.

How to insert this data into the Mysql database properly?

Example of the data required in a dataframe

```
col1             col2     col3      col4

8465-01-446-8616 06222  MODEL 703   
8465-01-538-4334 0N995  PMBS9      AARDVARK
8465-01-538-4334 12858  BS-9       PAULSON MANUFACTURING CORPORATION
8345-01-641-8205 58367  24425HBA   WILLARD MARINE, INC.
8345-01-641-8205 58367  37210      WILLARD MARINE, INC.
```

First row is empty.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the mistake is with the way you are interpreting the data. Each of the original four columns has 10 elements, some of which are empty. Each element of columns 2 to 4 is a list. When you do `sum(col2,[])` you flatten the list, destroying the original alignment. Also, the length of cols 2 to 4 goes to 11 elements instead of 10 (the effect of the various length of the sublists composing each column). You should probably better understand how your data is structured and, maybe, accept lists as elements of your database

Comment: there is a mistake with `sum(col2,[])`. So I want to avoid this and create the list of tuples as in the expected output.

Comment: I would place all the data in a Pandas Dataframe. Pandas have a built-in function to insert your Dataframe into a database.

Comment: @Herker can you please illustrate how to, I also think using pandas would be helpful

Comment: @AtomStore can you share your database table?

Comment: I have updated how the dataframe should look like

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work!

**Required Imports:**

```
 import mysql.connector
 from sqlalchemy import create_engine
 import pandas as pd
```

Connection to your database:

```
sqlEngine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:root@localhost/DATABASE NAME')
dbConnection = sqlEngine.connect()
db = mysql.connector.connect(

   host="localhost",
   user="username",
   passwd="password",
   database="database name")

mycursor = db.cursor()


col1 = ['', '8465-01-446-8616', '8465-01-538-4334', '8345-01-641-8205', '8465-01-690-3107', '8465-01-526-7827', '', '', '5120-00-097-4136', '6640-00-866-1645']

col2 = ['', '06222', '0N995', '12858', '58367', '58367', '4SEN6', '0CCM0', '', '', '82523', '8BXN8', '1KGE8', '725Q0']

col3 = ['', 'MODEL 703', 'PMBS9', 'BS-9', '24425HBA', '37210', 'MA66-002', '03485', '', '', '100250', '5080', '09-845C', '4716E20']
 
col4 = ['', 'AARDVARK', 'PAULSON MANUFACTURING CORPORATION', 'WILLARD MARINE, INC.', 'WILLARD MARINE, INC.', 'CONDOR OUTDOOR PRODUCTS, INC.', 'CASCADE DESIGNS, INC.', '', '', '', 'TELEFLEX LLC', 'FISHER SCIENTIFIC COMPANY L.L.C.', 'THOMAS SCIENTIFIC, LLC']
 
data = {
    'col1': col1,
    'col2': col2,
    'col3': col3,
    'col4': col4
}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')
df = df.transpose()
df.to_sql(con=sqlEngine, name="table name", if_exists='append', index=False)
```

> The `transpose()` function transposes the index and columns of the dataframe. It reflects the DataFrame over its main diagonal by writing rows as columns and vice-versa.